# How do I use a 2 dimensional array for accessing data in a file using Perl?

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

I am new to Perl coding & am facing a situation. Here is the problem statement:

I have a file which contains some data (only numbers) in matrix form like

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 .......
7 9 4 6 7 8 .......
...................
...................
```

I have another file which contains 2 rows of data (some coordinates) like

```
30 50
04 09
80 90
.. ..
.. ..
```

These are the coordinates of data situated in the first file, I want to extract that data from the first file & paste in the 3rd row in the second file, for example in the first case I have to search the element in 30th row & 50th column in the first file & paste it in the 1st row 3rd column of the second file.

Comment: I want to put the contents of first file into a two dimensional array then using split I will get the data from the second file & use that data to access that particular element in the first array. I used to do C programming where I directly used 2 dim array but here I am having difficulty in getting the syntax of how to use this array

Comment: Ok, what have you tried in Perl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't hard.

First, you will have to parse the value matrix. If the input is in the filehandle `$fh`, then you could do:

```
my @data;
while(<$fh>) {
  chomp;              # remove newline
  my @row = split;    # split the current line on whitespace
  push @data, \@row;  # put a reference to this row into @data.
}
```

Arrays can only contain scalars, so we have to put a reference of the row into our data matrix.

The above could be written as

```
my @data = map { chomp; [split] } <$fh>;
```

instead; the `[...]` produces an anonymous arrayref, and `map` transforms a list by applying the action in the block.

The data can be accessed like `$data[$y][$x]`. If you want to swap the indices, this becomes akward in Perl, but isn't impossible.

To access the data at the coordinates from the second file (I'll assume the filehandle is `$fh2`), we just split those lines and look up the element:

```
while (<$fh2>) {
  chomp;
  my ($x, $y) = split;
  say "at x=$x, y=$y there is $data[$y][$x]";
}
```

Be sure to `use strict; use warnings;` at the top of each script to catch errors. `say` needs perl 5.10 or later.

Comment: thnx for ur help I will try it out, Hey I was trying this small script in windows 

#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
open ("FH","<<","D:/V.xls");
@f = <FH>;
foreach  $eachline(@f)
{
@x=split(' ',$eachline);
print "$x[1]\t$x[2]";
}
but I am getting an error in cmd line saying
"Global symbol @f requires explicit package name c" . Can u help me with that?

Comment: @Samir under `strict`, Perl requires you to declare all your variables; this is a good thing. You can declare with `my` (is remotely similar to `auto` in C): `my @f = <FH>; ... my @x = split ...`. Also, consider using "lexical filehandles": `open my $fh, "<", "D:/V.xls" or die "Can't open file: $!";` ← first arg is *not* a string; there is no `<<` open mode, added error handling.